# Question: "Qualified Dividends and Capital Gain Tax Worksheet -- line 12a" 1040 2019

Tags: united-states, capital-gains-tax, form-1040, schedule-d

2019 was not a good year and my taxable income(1040 line 11b) is $3600.

I had dividend and LTCG income so **Schedule D** sends me to this worksheet:   **Qualified Dividends and Capital Gains** (page 33, 1040 instructions).

I had expected to pay no federal tax, but am getting hung up on question #24 on this Worksheet.

```
24. Figure the tax on the amount on line 7. 
If the amount on line 7 is less than $100,000, use the Tax Table to figure the tax. 
If the amount on line 7 is $100,000 or more, use the Tax Computation  Worksheet
```

In my case, **line 7 is $0**.  But if I follow these directions to Tax Table and use $3600 (line 11b), I do have a tax to pay, which flows to end of this form.

Have I interpreted line #24 correctly?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You missed an important part of that quote of Line 24: "Figure the tax *on the amount on line 7*" (emphasis mine). The tax on $0 is $0.

Comment: To me, Tax Table is  explicit:   **"If line 11b (taxable income) is --"**   [Suspect you are correct, though!]